# Git: origin/head/master stuck on a branch

Tags: git

We were having some trouble with our cloudforge git repository today. After a support ticket they claimed to have "resynced" it.

On top of it we are a team of developers with different git versions on different platforms.

The user Paul has tried to commit/push with a combination of TortoiseGit, git gui and git bash.  To my surprise it seems he has created a branch and merged it again himself.

But now the origin/head , origin/master seem to be stuck on the branch rather than on latest.  I am confused. Shouldn't the HEAD be on top?

[image]

Comment: Have you pushed to `origin`? Or is this the state of your local repo after pulling in the changes introduced up until "apple bug"?

Comment: Will, I am on linux and did a `git push origin master`. You see my push as the light blue (Origin/HEAD). And Paul did a commit/push on Windows after me (see golden master/ Apple bug). He pushed to `push test master` ( `local - master`, `remote - master`, `destination remote-origin`). Did seem to have pushed it wrongly right? How can I fix this please?

Comment: Have you fetched from origin?  If you update with `git pull` instead of `git fetch` the local copies of remotes may not be updated.

Comment: Andrew, I do git pull origin master. But he is using Windows apps. Is there no way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

ok good news. I don't know how to set the setting on windows machines, but told him to make sure pushing into `origin master` and not just `master`.

This seems to have solved it automatically. I will obverse this and update this answer if necessary.

[image]